# How to manipulate recursively nested elements in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, nested

I have a very basic todo list with add todo, toggle complete and delete functionality. I want to be able to have infinitely nested todos. I managed to figure out how to display nested todos through recursion but I can't figure out how to manipulate the nested elements recursively.

When I interact with an element I get the correct id back to the functions in the main component but I also need the id of the parent. I was able to manipulate data one layer deep by making new functions that took two parameters instead of one, the parent id and the target id but of course this defeats the purpose of having recursive nesting. I have also considered giving up the recursive approach and changing to a flat data structure where the nested elements have a reference to the parent instead.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

    const data = {
      todos: [
        {
          id: 'a',
          text: 'go shopping',
          subTodos: [
            {
              id: 'aa',
              text: 'buy fruit',
              subTodos: [
                {
                  id: 'aaa',
                  text: 'oranges',
                  subTodos: [],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 'b',
          text: 'learn recursion',
          subTodos: []
        },
      ],
    };
    
    const Todos = () => {
    
      const [todos, setTodos] = useState(data);
      
      const handleDelete = (id) => {
        const newTodoArray = todos.todos.filter(todo => (todo.id !== id))
        setTodos(prev => ({...prev, todos: newTodoArray}))
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          {todos.todos.map(todo => (
            <Todo
              key={todo.id}
              todo={todo}
              handleDelete={handleDelete}/>
            ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    const Todo = ({todo, handleDelete}) => {
      return (
        <div key={todo.id} style={{paddingLeft: '20px'}}>
          <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
            <div>{todo.text}</div> 
            <button onClick={() => handleDelete(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            {todo.subTodos.map((todo) => (
            <Todo
              key={todo.id}
              todo={todo}
              handleDelete={handleDelete}>
            </Todo>))
            }
           </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default Todos;
```

I would appreciate any advice regarding my approach or any resources that could be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right way to handle this would be to put each sublist from props into *state* of the sub-todo component. When a todo needs to be deleted, tell the parent todo (or the parent `Todos`, in the case of the top level) to delete the item from state. This way, each todo handles its children's state, and when a click occurs, you don't have to recursively iterate all the way back to the parent (which would make for some tedious nested object traversal when you need to set state again).

```
const Todo = ({ todo, handleDelete }) => {
    const [subTodos, setSubTodos] = React.useState(todo.subTodos);
    const handleSubTodoDelete = (id) => {
        setSubTodos(subTodos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id));
    }
    return (
        <div key={todo.id} style={{ paddingLeft: '20px' }}>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                <div>{todo.text}</div>
                <button onClick={() => handleDelete(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                {subTodos.map((todo) => (
                    <Todo
                        key={todo.id}
                        todo={todo}
                        handleDelete={handleSubTodoDelete}>
                    </Todo>))
```

Here's a live snippet:

```js
const data = {
    todos: [
        {
            id: 'a',
            text: 'go shopping',
            subTodos: [
                {
                    id: 'aa',
                    text: 'buy fruit',
                    subTodos: [
                        {
                            id: 'aaa',
                            text: 'oranges',
                            subTodos: [],
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            id: 'b',
            text: 'learn recursion',
            subTodos: []
        },
    ],
};

const Todos = () => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState(data);
    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        const newTodoArray = todos.todos.filter(todo => (todo.id !== id))
        setTodos(prev => ({ ...prev, todos: newTodoArray }))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {todos.todos.map(todo => (
                <Todo
                    key={todo.id}
                    todo={todo}
                    handleDelete={handleDelete} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

const Todo = ({ todo, handleDelete }) => {
    const [subTodos, setSubTodos] = React.useState(todo.subTodos);
    const handleSubTodoDelete = (id) => {
        setSubTodos(subTodos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id));
    }
    return (
        <div key={todo.id} style={{ paddingLeft: '20px' }}>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                <div>{todo.text}</div>
                <button onClick={() => handleDelete(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                {subTodos.map((todo) => (
                    <Todo
                        key={todo.id}
                        todo={todo}
                        handleDelete={handleSubTodoDelete}>
                    </Todo>))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

    
ReactDOM.render(<Todos />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

The `handleDelete` prop is created in the parent and passed down as a prop. In each child, a `handleSubTodoDelete` function is created and passed down to manage that child's state.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. I have run into a problem using this approach. Since any changes only exist in the local state I cant make the application persistent. Only changes to the top level are actually ever stored.